# How to resolve virtual network adapter instance name of Hyper-V Virtual Network Adapter in PerformanceCounter

Tags: performance, wmi, hyper-v

I would like to build a network usage report of each partition of Hyper-V.
To do that, I try to dump all the network metrics(Hyper-V Virtual Network Adapter) from PerformanceCounter via wmi.

But when I see the data, the instance name of performance data is something like 'virtweb1_Network Adapter_db2bd5a6-d1fb-47d3-9856-905f6097a733--9da63530-a976-4a80-8c22-d798498a9d3d'.
What I would like to do is, extrace partition name from it and summarize all the instances by partition and report aggregated network usage.

I looked for the naming pattern of these instance names, but could not find one.
Does anybody tell me the naming pattern of these instance names?